# Mock static throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, static, mocking

I try to write test then it use static class.

I have class Person:

```
public class Person {
  private int id;
  public Person(String name) {
    id = Id.generate(name);
  }
  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }
}
```

And class Id:

```
public class Id {
  public static int generate(String name) {
    if (name.equals("I")) {
      return 42;
    }
    return 100;
  }
}
```

This is my test:

```
import org.easymock.EasyMock;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock;

import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest( { Id.class } )
public class MockStaticTest {

  @Test
  public void test() throws Exception {
    PowerMock.mockStatic(Id.class);
    EasyMock.expect(Id.generate(null)).andReturn(55);

    PowerMock.replayAll();
    Person person = new Person(null);
    Assert.assertEquals(person.getId(), 55);
    PowerMock.verifyAll();
  }
}
```

When I run test, it throws NPE:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Id.generate(Id.java:3)
    at MockStaticTest.test(MockStaticTest.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
...
```

On line 17 it calls code of static method Id.generate. In my opinion, it is wrong behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution.
Test class must extend PowerMockTestCase.

Correctly:

```
public class MockStaticTest extends PowerMockTestCase {
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Calling `new Person(null)` will throw this exception as the constructor calls `generate(name)` and `generate` calls `name.equals`. *That* is your problem: `name` is `null`.

One way round this in your case would be to use the *Yoda condition* `"I".equals(name)`. Although this looks odd at first glance, it does allow you to rely on `java.lang.String` making a `null` check in `.equals`, meaning you don't have to do it yourself.

Comment: I know that NPE throw `name.equals("I")`, it is the intention. This is proof that `EasyMock.expect(Id.generate(null)).andReturn(55);` call `Id.generate(null)`. In my opinion, this is wrong behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `null` as an argument, then why should it not give a `NullPointerException`? 
At line 17 you should give a proper argument.